# how to get a custom DateTime format of a column of type DateTime in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite

i have a column InsertionDT of type DateTime('now')
what i want is to select this column but only displaye the Time (without date)

```
select strftime('%H:%M:%S',DateTime('now') ) AS MSGDT from TableA  //this works
select strftime('%H:%M:%S',Insertiondt) AS MSGDT from TableA  //this is what i want
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the stamp you created:

`CREATE TABLE dates (id int, InsertioDT datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);`

Instead of (DATETIME('now')).

Then `SELECT strftime('%H:%M:%S', InsertioDT) AS MSGDT from TableA`

Tell us if it worked.

It worked for me.

[image]

Comment: I did try that and its written in my question but it returned an empty column

Comment: Ok it is a column set problem. Check the column param, what type of data is it.

Comment: [InsertionDT] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (DATETIME('now')),

Comment: thats the column in the create table query

Comment: Is it a 1 column table?